# list characters in arrays without duplicate

Tags: c, arrays

Well, my question is pretty simple, yet i've been stuck for quite a while. I'd like to write a program that takes two arrays as arguments, and then write the letters in it without duplicates, in order of appearance.

example :

```
$ ./a.out bulwark blue
bulwarke

$ ./a.out fresh feeling
freshling

$ ./a.out final01 test02
final01tes2
```

I tried a few ways, but can't figure how to do it without `malloc`. The tricky thing is, I cannot use `malloc`, the only authorized function is "write"

P.S : Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Why do you need `malloc`?

Comment: the words are just argv[1] and argv[2]. So you could just use strlen and work it out. I feel there is no need of malloc.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the arrays?

Comment: Can you show your best coding attempt?

Comment: Read about [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: This doesn't need dynamic arrays, malloc or sorting - it's a very simple algorithm.

Comment: alirhgt, the cloesst thing I got was a program that sorted the first array, then the second one, but couldn't work on both. I figured out my problem : I was checking every character, and writing it down unless I found  a duplicate somewhere. The thing is, my algorithm looked like that :

while (array[i] != '\0')
{
if (array[i] == char c && check == 0)
printf(array[i]);
check++;}
The thing is, the algorithm would always reset for every character, so in the end, "eleven" would still be "eleven". I just changed the "while" to solve the problem

Comment: Your above comment is good, but it should be part of your question.  Please use the "edit" link to add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an auxiliary array to indicate which letter has already been used:

```
void func(char arr1[],char arr2[])
{
    int hash[256] = {0};
    for (int i=0; arr1[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        unsigned char letter = (unsigned char)arr1[i];
        if (hash[letter] == 0)
        {
            hash[letter] = 1;
            printf("%c",letter);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; arr2[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        unsigned char letter = (unsigned char)arr2[i];
        if (hash[letter] == 0)
        {
            hash[letter] = 1;
            printf("%c",letter);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Note:** this code assumes that each of the input strings (`arr1` and `arr2`) is terminated with a 0 character.

Comment: Note that `char` may be signed.

Comment: Yep; good comment; just fixed the first issue of ']', and will fix the second issue in a minute.

Comment: Not a problem if the input is pure ASCII of course.

Comment: Thought I'd mention that in the notes, but the function takes two `char` arrays, so...

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track what you have printed. The follow will work just fine for char, because there are so few of them. Keeping track of unicode chars with an array that is long enough for all possible values would be mad. In such case inserting identifiers to a hash would probably be better option, but since unicode was not part of the consideration the following should be good enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char arr[256] = { 0 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        for (j = 0; argv[i][j]; j++)
            if (!arr[argv[i][j]]) {
                arr[argv[i][j]] = 1;
                printf("%c", argv[i][j]);
            }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that char may be signed.